# Traefik 2.2 Gateway timeout issue

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have been trying to setup traefik v2.2 using the basic official guide. I have a spring boot service which I have containerized and is working properly.

Here's docker compose of my spring boot service :

```
version: "3"

services:
  spring-boot-traefik-app:
    image: spring-boot-traefik-example:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.spring-boot-traefik-app.rule=Host(`springboot.traefik.app`)"
```

and Here's my Traefik docker compose :

```
version: "3"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.2
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Now, I'm trying to do a curl request by :

```
curl -H Host:springboot.traefik.app http://127.0.0.1
```

As I'm just returning the service info on the context path "/", it should have returned me something. Service is working fine independently. But when I'm trying run behind the proxy it gives me Gateway Timeout error. I'm not sure if traefik is working properly. Am I missing something? The official guide uses whoami image which is what I'm trying to create with Spring boot. Also, traefik dashboard shows the details correctly.

Comment: Hi, did you end up resolving this? I have the same issue. Using file configs and springboot app and just get a gateway timeout.

Comment: Hey @Dan, I could not find a solution for this. Luckily this was my pet project and things were working fine with the older Traefik version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define an entrypoint for your traefik configuration. You may not have a traefik.toml file (I prefer using this personally). Anyway, you should add the command `--entryPoints.web.address=:80` for your traefik container and add the label `traefik.http.routers.spring-boot-traefik-app.entrypoints=web` in your springboot container. I hope it works !

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work. Gateway times out